# Convolution of which distribution will give a uniform distribution?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, convolution, economics

Suppose there are two IID random variables x1 and x2. What should be the distribution of these random variables so that the distribution of x1-x2 is a uniform distribution?

Comment: The density of $X-Y$ is the _autocorrelation_ function of the common density of the IID random variables $X$ and $Y$, and _no_ autocorrelation function can have the shape (uniform density) that you desire. Thus, your question "What should be the distribution..." has no answer.